# How to get a row even if it fails inner join condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

We have a scenario where we want all the data which satisfies inner join also one more record even if it fails join condition.
To include that one unmatched record we have primary key value, we can not apply Left join coz it include all the unmatched records from left table but we are interested in only 1.

ex.  We have a primary key value Id = 3.

Table 1:

```
Table1_ID   Table1_Name
   1          Test
   2          Test_1
   3          Test_2
```

Table 2:

```
Table2_ID   Table2_Name
   1          Test
```

Expected result:

```
  ID    Name
  1      Test
  3      Test3
```

Comment: Simply [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) your inner join result with that specific record?

Comment: Please show your current query. Probably you can change the `inner join` to a `left join` with a `where` clause that meets your requirements.

Comment: The name `Test3` in your expected result doesn't match any name in the input.

Comment: What is the criteria for the unmatched record -- that it has id = 3 or some other criteria?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use `LEFT JOIN`, then filter un-matched records in `WHERE` conditions

```
SELECT t1.Table1_ID AS ID, t1.Table1_Name AS Name
FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.Table1_ID = t2.Table2_ID)
WHERE (t2.Table2_ID IS NOT NULL OR t1.Table1_ID = 3)
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pXJCJMsv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) to treat two queries as one.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

union

select *
from table1
where id = 3
```